# Крашеные под зебру волосы: Н или НН?

Tags: орфография

1) В оригинале написана **одна буква Н**, но по формальному правилу (при наличии зависимого слова) нужно писать **две буквы НН**:

а) красить волосы - крашеные (ненатуральные) волосы, прилагательное, качественный признак, возможна замена синонимом, одна буква Н.

б) красить волосы под зебру - крашенные под зебру волосы, причастие, признак по действию, две буквы НН.

Но здесь **зависимое слово переходит к причастию из глагольного сочетания**.

2) А если такой вариант: Многим не нравятся **явно крашеные** (ненатуральные) волосы.

Здесь **зависимое слово относится именно к прилагательному** (не переходит от глагола), оно определяет степень качества.

**Вопрос:** Следует ли в том случае писать "явно крашенные" с двумя буквами НН и считать отглагольную форму причастием, то есть следовать формальному правилу?

Comment: Вера, а здесь и нет ощущается временной признак. Если следовать формальному признаку, получится: волосы, которые явно покрасили. Ведь надо исходить не только из формальный структуры, но и учитывать семантику.

Comment: Серж, так как правильно писать, это прилагательное (Н)   или причастие (НН)? В Сети пишут как кому нравится, так же не должно быть.  И ответьте, пожалуйста на вопрос, а не в комментарии.

Comment: Вера, вы имеете в виду "Крашеные под зебру волосы''? Или "явно крашеные"?

Comment: И то и другое.  Как вы напишете и как объясните?

Comment: Дал бы +10 за вопрос, если бы можно было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "**крашенные**" (причастие), относится к процессу, а не к результату (для него возможно "окрашенные" или "раскрашенные"). В этом слове явный оттенок незавершённости действия: это либо "недокрашенность" (начали было и бросили красить), либо повторявшееся в прошлом окрашивание (несколько раз крашенные под зебру волосы стали выпадать полосами). В выражении "явно крашенные (под зебру)" акцент на то, что с волосами делали нечто конкретное (остались следы этого действия), и просматривается противопоставление какому-то мнению. Если смысл в этом, то видимо, так и надо написать.

"**Крашеные**" (прилагательное) под зебру, вероятно, было бы оправданным для характеристики результата (кажется, в своё время Вы обосновывали "вяленый на солнце", "жареный в сметане или на сковороде"), если бы не простая возможность выбрать для такого случая причастие (-нн-) совершенного вида (с приставкой; к зебре больше подходит "рас-").

Comment: От глагола несовершенного вида красить можно образовать только прилагательное, обозначающее непроцессуальный  (вневременной) признак (красить - крашеный, то есть обработанный краской, а не чем-нибудь еще). Причастие в принципе можно образовать только от глагола совершенного вида: раскрасить - раскрашенный. А откуда тогда  берется причастие "крашенный"? Наверное, значение времени эта форма может получить от зависимого слова с временным значением: крашенный в прошлом году забор.

Comment: А если крашенный зеленой краской - это прилагательное или причастие?  Больше похоже на прилагательное, зависимое слово просто уточняет качественный признак. Из этого следует, что зависимые слова бывают разными, хотелось бы учитывать их значение. Тогда явно крашеные волосы и крашеные под зебру волосы надо писать с одной Н, что в большинстве случаев и делается.

Comment: "Крашенный (зелёной краской)" - причастие, означающее, что нечто красили этой краской - с неясным результатом  (не раз красили, либо недокрасили). В противном случае нужно "покрашенный" или "окрашенный".

Comment: Крашеный забор - это просто прилагательное, результат здесь как раз имеется и не обсуждается в подробностях, это качественный признак, не отнесенный ко времени, как в обычных прилагательных, образованных не от глаголов. А "зеленой краской" - это зеленый крашеный забор.

Comment: И я так считаю; здесь действие покраски забыто и речь о свойствах. Краска осталась в виде слоя.

Comment: Вера, а почему Вы считаете, что ''От глагола несовершенного вида красить можно образовать только прилагательное, обозначающее непроцессуальный (вневременной) признак (красить - крашеный, то есть обработанный краской, а не чем-нибудь еще). Крашенный осенью забор - разве не причастие? Здесь даже сомнений не вызывает. Или я Вас не так понял?

Comment: В вашем примере " Крашеные под зебру волосы''  причастие. Здесь трудно увидеть постоянный признак-качество. На лицо временной признак: волосы, которые покрасили под зебру.

Answer (score 0):

```
Крашеные под зебру волосы
```

Все попытки разобраться, что здесь: причастие (тогда почему одно н?) или прилагательное (но ведь есть зависимые слова!) обречены на провал.
Дело в том, что "крашеные под зебру" - это **ОДНО** (составное) цельное прилагательное - нельзя вычленить его часть и рассматривать отдельно!
(По крайней мере, автор так считает - и небезосновательно.)
Сложно поверить? Проверьте!
Наше составное прилагательное "крашеные под зебру" легко без потери смысла заменить на прилагательное *полосатые* или *линейчатые*, а то и вовсе перестроить в словосочетание *волосы в полоску*.
Попробуйте провести такую рокировку в причастном словосочетании "жаренный в сметане карась".

"Многим не нравятся явно крашеные (ненатуральные) волосы."
Действительно, есть зависимое слово, относится именно к прилагательному и определяет степень качества. Ну так у прилагательных **МОГУТ** быть зависимые слова - как раз в виде наречий меры и степени: совершенно зелёный забор, слегка мутная жидкость; так что попытка цепляя их выявить причастие наивна - они одинаково хорошо прилепятся и к прилагательному, и к причастию (как носителю многих свойств прилагательного): явно плохой метод; явно не подходящий нам метод.
На процессуальный признак могут указывать пояснительные слова: крашеные (как? где? зачем? и т. п. наречные вопросы) - здесь их нет; зато вы сами без потери смысла заменили сомнительное слово на прилагательное - значит там ему и место.

В словосочетании "крашенный зелёной краской", *крашенный* - причастие, потому что есть зависимое слово, да... Но это не *зелёной*. Крашенный (как? когда? где? почему? и т. п.) зелёной?
Краской (какой?) зелёной. Имя прилагательное *зелёной* - зависимое слово имени существительного *краска*!
Крашенный (чем?) краской - вот подчинительная связь, так что просто "крашенный краской" (даже не зелёной!) - словосочетание, в котором причастие *крашенный* обозначает признак предмета по действию, на что указывает предмет действия *краска*.
Крашенный (когда?) осенью забор - тоже причастное словосочетание, так как есть обстоятельство действия.

---

**ВАЖНО**
Действительно, "зависимые слова бывают разными"; не забываем следить от каких именно слов они зависят, где их хозяин!

Comment: Можно ли где-то почитать про то, что есть зависимые слова, а что – нет? :)

Comment: И как вы тогда объясните этот текст: он был совсем не хорош собой и странен, - очки, котелок, 
 английское пальто, а волосы редких усов точно конские, смуглая тонкая кожа на плоском лице точно натянута и как будто слегка лакироваНа " (c) Бунин. По такой логике, слегка - это тоже не зависимое слово, а значит лакированная - прилагательное, а значит в краткой форме должно быть две НН?