# Будут ли слова "очень", "весьма" (и подобные) выступать как зависимые к причастию?

Tags: причастия

```
В магазине, гипотетический диалог:

- Мне нужна мороженая рыба!
- Пожалуйста! Этот кусок рыбы очень/абсолютно/полностью/вполне мороже(Н, НН)ый.
```

"Мороже(Н, НН)ый *насколько/сильно/как?* очень/абсолютно/полностью/вполне" - зависимые слова. Значит, это причастие, и надо писать две НН?

**UPDATE:**

```
он был совсем не хорош собой и странен, - очки, котелок, 
английское пальто, а волосы редких усов точно конские, 
смуглая тонкая кожа на плоском лице точно натянута и как 
будто -->>> слегка лакироваНа <<---- (c) Бунин
```

"слегка лакирована", "лакирована" как? "слегка". То есть, в данном случае "лакированный" - это причастие, а не отглагольное прилагательное, из-за зависимого слова?

**UPDATE 2**: нашел похожую тему [Крашеные под зебру волосы: Н или НН?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418518) , правда, ответы участников разные

Answer (score 2):

```
 Будут ли слова "очень", "весьма" (и подобные) выступать как 
 зависимые к причастию? 

 Из комментариев
 — Так что не переводят они прилагательное в причастие. В 
 общем случае зависимые слова ("переводящие прилагательные в 
 причастия") — это все слова, кроме наречий меры и степени.
 — Вот!!! про это я и пытаюсь выяснить! И я бы очень хотел 
  увидеть их где-нибудь в том же Розентале, например.
```

1. Нет, **не будут** эти слова выступать как  зависимые к причастию.  [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77) упоминает эти наречия в теме "Правописание НЕ с прилагательными". Обратим внимание на то, что речь идет о **качественных** прилагательных (не об отглагольных).

   ```
   Пункт 6. Наличие пояснительных слов, как правило, не 
   влияет на слитное написание частицы не с прилагательными 
   (ср. написание не с причастиями): незнакомый нам автор; 
   неизвестные науке факты; неуместное в данных условиях 
   замечание; незаметная на первый взгляд ошибка и т.д. 

   Если в качестве пояснительного слова выступает **наречие 
   меры и степени** (весьма, крайне, очень, почти или 
   наречное выражение в высшей степени и т. п.), то частица 
   НЕ **с прилагательным** всегда пишется слитно: весьма 
   некрасивый поступок; крайне неуместный выпад; очень 
   неудачное выступление; почти незнакомый текст; в высшей 
   степени неразборчивый почерк.
   ```
2. Наречия меры и степени изучаются [в грамматике](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77) при различении качественных и относительных прилагательных.

**Качественные** прилагательные: способность сочетаться **с наречиями меры и степени** «очень», «совершенно», «крайне», «чрезвычайно», «совсем» и пр.: очень тяжелый рюкзак; крайне обидное замечание; совсем грустное настроение.

**Относительные** прилагательные: не имеют грамматических признаков, которыми обладают качественные прилагательные. Они не могут менять **интенсивность (количество)** признака, то есть не имеют степеней сравнения; не сочетаются **с наречиями меры и степени;** не образуют краткой формы;  не имеют синонимов и антонимов.

3. **Отглагольные** прилагательные являются **относительными** (отношение к действию) и поэтому не соединяются с наречиями меры и степени. С **причастиями** они также не соединяются. Нельзя сказать: *Этот кусок рыбы очень мороженый. —  А очень замороженный? —  Если только в разговорном стиле.*
4. О наречии ***слегка***

**СЛЕГКА** [хк], нареч. Немного, чуть-чуть. С. кивнуть. С. прикоснуться. С. толкнуть. С. испугался. С. проголодался. С. картавит. // Вскользь, мимоходом, не вдаваясь в подробности. С. упомянуть о чём-л. С. коснуться какого-л. вопроса. С. затронуть какую-л. тему.

Это наречие сочетается **с глаголами и причастиями**, соответственно, наречием меры и степени **не является**. Нельзя сказать: *слегка тяжелый*. Поэтому *кожа будто слегка лакирована* — это краткое причастие.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Хочу уточнить про "наречие сочетается с глаголами и причастиями, соответственно, наречием меры и степени не является". Здесь (https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/narechie/mery-i-stepeni.html) указывают его как наречие меры и степени и приводят такой пример: "исправить (в какой степени?) слегка"...

Comment: Пока я могу сказать вот что. В словаре Ефремовой дана такая информация: (1)  Слегка, нареч. качеств.-обстоят. разг.  (2) Очень, нареч. качеств.-количеств. 1. Употребляется как усилитель неопределённо большого КОЛИЧЕСТВА кого-либо или чего-либо. 2. Употребляется как усилитель степени проявления каких-либо свойств, качеств и т.п.; в сильной, в высокой, в значительной степени.  В грамматике про наречие слегка указано: с оттенком ослабления признака или действия. Поэтому статус у слов разный, сочетаемость тоже.  И вывод: подходите к каждому наречию индивидуально.  Общего списка не получится.

Comment: Прочитайте еще вот эту статью: http://rusgram.ru/Наречие# 
 5.3.2. Наречия меры и степени  Наречия меры и степени характеризуют интенсивность проявления признака, Наречия меры и степени сочетаются также с глаголами, содержащими в семантике ИЗМЕРЯЕМЫЙ градуируемый) компонент.

Comment: Тест.  Привезли с дачи мороже(...)ые яблоки, слегка мороже(...)ые яблоки. Мороже(...)ые в холодильнике яблоки.

Comment: Так как и "лакированный"  – кач. п., и "лакировать" имеет "градиентность" ("Очень важным является способ нанесения лака на поверхность. Золотое правило при лакировке — лучше несколько тонких слоев, чем один толстый."), то я не уверен, что употребление "слегка" отправляет автоматически это слово в причастия. Мне кажется, ваше утверждение в ответе  не вполне верно ("Это наречие сочетается с глаголами и причастиями, соответственно, наречием меры и степени не является")...

Comment: Я бы сказал наоборот, что с прил. более естественно звучит ("слегка лакированный стол" vs "стол, слегка лакированный мастером,..." – так разве говорят?), а в примере употребляется в переносном значении, в котором еще более сильно развита градация.

Comment: Не сошлись во мнениях)) См. словарь: ЛАКИРОВАННЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Покрытый лаком. Л. паркет, пол. // Сделанный из кожи, покрытой лаком. Л-ые туфли.   И не более того, остальное – фантазии.  Слегка –  оттенок ослабления, а не усилительное слово (из грамматики).  Мы не можем  (в одном вопросе) обсуждать все наречия, какие есть.  Это наречие не входит в группу очень, весьма и т.д. (усилительные слова).  А вообще говоря, тема получилось растянутой (на три вопроса хватит, а то и больше).  Тогда бы у нас был не диалог, а обсуждение с другими участниками.

Comment: Соглашусь. :)  Спасибо вам за внимание, было интересно. Да, я бы с удовольствием услышал мнение других участников. Похоже, всех распугал :(

Comment: Вот и задайте конкретный вопрос по предложению из Бунина. Пусть тоже подумают. Обозначьте разные мнения (мое и ваше).

Answer (score 1):

```
"Все ответы (или почти все) есть в словаре". Mytrend
```

*Действительно, зачем самим решать? Лучше найти ответ в словаре.*

1. [Мороженый](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42&dicts%5B%5D=71)

Русский орфографический словарь: ***мороженый***, прил.

Большой толковый словарь.
**МОРОЖЕНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. Подвергшийся замораживанию, воздействию холода. М-ая рыба. М-ые яблоки. М. картофель.

**Метасловарь**. Прилагательное. Подвергшийся замораживанию, воздействию холода. М-ая рыба. М-ые яблоки. М. картофель.

Глагол [морозить](https://gramota.ru/meta/morozit) имеет три формы причастия, в том числе форму ***мороженный*** (при наличии зависимых слов).

**Вывод:** Мороженый — **относительное** прилагательное.

```
 Рыба в магазине бывает охлажденная и мороженая, это 
 термины. Мороженой называют рыбу, температура которой в 
 толще мышечной ткани поддерживается на уровне от - 18 °С и 
 ниже.

 Грамматическая справка
 Качественные прилагательные обозначают признак, который 
 может быть выражен в большей или меньшей степени.  Такие 
 прилагательные образуют словосочетания с наречиями меры и 
 степени, которые указывают на степень проявления признака: 
 весьма (не)привлекательный, совершенно серьезный, совсем 
 молодой, очень вкусный. Относительные прилагательные 
 называют такой признак, который количественно не меняется и 
 создается только опосредованно, через отношение к чему- 
 либо. Соответственно, они не образуют словосочетания  с 
 наречиями меры и степени.
```

Поэтому сочетание ***очень мороженая*** некорректно. Речь могла идти о частично размороженной рыбе по сравнению с  замороженной по стандарту.

2. [Лакированный](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42&dicts%5B%5D=71)

Русский орфографический словарь: ***лакированный***; кр. ф. **-ан, -ана.**  Но такую форму могут иметь как прилагательные, так и причастия.

Большой толковый словарь
**ЛАКИРОВАННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. Покрытый лаком. Л. паркет, пол. // Сделанный из кожи, покрытой лаком. Л-ые туфли.

Отдельную словарную статью имеют прилагательные, но не причастия.

**Метасловарь**: Прилагательное, **качественное.**

Это вряд ли. Отглагольные прилагательные **относительные**, и им не положено иметь краткую форму и наречия степени.

Глагол [лакировать](https://%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) **несовершенного** вида, причастная форма лакированный под вопросом. В словаре Евгеньевой эта форма есть, но больше вроде бы нет. В то же время **единичные** употребления краткой формы возможны.

**Вывод:** при использовании краткой формы это **причастие** (в краткой форме по словарю **-ан, -ана**).

В приведенном тексте это **краткое причастие** (признак по действию). К тому же это сравнение: *как будто слегка лакирована.*

```
Он по росту казался среди других мальчиком, он был совсем не 
хорош собой и странен – очки, котелок, английское пальто, а 
волосы редких усов точно конские, смуглая тонкая кожа на 
плоском лице точно натянута и как будто слегка лакирована
```

3. [Крашеный](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42&dicts%5B%5D=71)

Русский орфографический словарь: **крашеный**, прил.

Большой толковый словарь.
**КРАШЕНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. 1. Покрытый краской, подвергшийся окраске. Воротник из крашеного песца. В комнате к. пол. К-ые волосы. К-ые яйца (пасхальные). 2. Разг. Имеющий накрашенное лицо, выкрашенные волосы (о человеке). К-ая блондинка, брюнетка.

**Метасловарь**: Прилагательное. Покрытый краской, подвергшийся окраске. Воротник из крашеного песца. В комнате к. пол. К-ые волосы. К-ые яйца

Глагол [красить](https://gramota.ru/meta/krasit) имеет **3 формы** причастий, в том числе ***крашенный***.

Вывод: ***крашеный*** — прилагательное, ***крашенный*** — причастие.

**Крашенный под зебру** — причастие. Это информация о том, что красили полосками ("как у зебры"). Здесь признак по действию (подвергшийся окраске), в отличие от ***крашеный*** (покрытый краской).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Все же я так и не понял, в каком случае зависимые слова позволяют переходить из причастия в прилагательное, а в каких – нет. Скажем, если я напишу "его кожа была слегка лакироваННа" (то есть употреблю лакированная как прилагательное), будет ли это ошибкой? Ведь есть же "зависимое слово", а значит – причастие?, значит так писать нельзя? (И Бунин, собственно, и не написал.)

Comment: Надо внимательно читать (РАСШИФРОВЫВАТЬ) словари. Русский орфографический словарь: лакированный; кр. ф. -ан, -ана.  Это указание для прилагательного. Для причастия одна буква Н пишется по общему правилу, специального указания не требуется.  Толковые словари предлагают считать лакированный прилагательным (покрытый лаком),  но в частном случае здесь чувствуется действие: кожу человека как бы слегка покрыли лаком. Но в ЛЮБОМ случае нужно писать одну букву Н.

Comment: Еще почитайте примеры https://kartaslov.ru/сочетаемость-слова/лакированный  Много ли там примеров с зависимыми словами? Может, они вообще не используются, а только  в частных случаях? И поэтому слово считают прилагательным?  Надо быть ближе к реальности)  То есть не подходить к информации формально, а стараться провести анализ.  Я вам предложила свое понимание того. что написано в словарях. Попробуйте сделать свои выводы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Я и пытаюсь сделать выводы, но пока не очень получается. Ведь есть же правило, что "в кратких прилагательных столько Н, сколько и в полных". Исключений вроде бы там нет. Как с этим быть?

Comment: Я уже давала эту информацию. Корректирующие правила как ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:  Розенталь § 48, пункт 7 и 8; ПАС под ред. Лопатина § 102.  И надо учитывать следующее:  обязательно сверяйте информацию со словарем РАН, он постоянно обновляется, в отличие от правил.

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62 - пункт 7 про краткое написание страдательных причастий и прилагательных, то, про что я и говорил. Пункт 8 про то, что *допускается* двоякое написание, то есть и так, и так правильно. Правильные выводы? ;)

Comment: Примечание 7-го пункта про глаголы с приставкой и совершенный вид, если я понимаю правильно. Что делать? лакировать. Вид несовершенный, приставки нет.

Comment: В полной форме пишется НН по правилу суффикс на ОВА, Смотрите в словарь РАН.   В Нацкорусе есть только наречие лакированно, других форм нет. С вами заодно только Шукшин, написал-таки НН:  Василий Шукшин. Версия (1972-1973) 
Ванна отделана голубым кафелем, туалет — желтым. Все блестит, мебель вся лакированна. Я сперва с осторожностью относился, она заметила, подняла на смех.  Вот такой он грамотей)

Comment: Вопрос про краткую. По правилу нужно писать две НН. Вы отвечаете: раз в словаре одна Н, пишем одну Н. Но меня интересует практическая сторона. Я ведь не буду все слова, которые пишу, проверять в словаре, в этом случае мне потребуется несколько часов, чтобы без ошибок написать этот ответ (и да, наверняка ошибок будет гораздо меньше :) ).  Или учить словари наизусть. Я пытаюсь понять, ПОЧЕМУ правило не работает, ПОЧЕМУ одна Н, а не две, ПОЧЕМУ в словаре так. Если это исключение, то есть ли список этих слов-исключений? Если это какой-то пункт правила, то что это за пункт, который объяснит?

Comment: И (просто чтобы "заземлить" эту дискуссию к теме вопроса): если "слегка" - зависимое слово, то это все объясняет: лакированное – причастие, и по правилу написания кратких причастий пишется одна Н. Остается вопрос про то, какие слова считать зависимыми, что я и пытаюсь выяснить :)

Comment: Ищете легких путей в жизни?))  Придется вас разочаровать:  в Нацкорпусе есть примеры причастий с одной Н и без зависимых слов. Так что не переводят они прилагательное в причастие. В общем случае  зависимые слова ("переводящие") - это все слова, кроме наречий меры и степени.

Comment: Вообще говоря, если уж прилагательное в краткой форме пишется с одной Н,  то происходит сближение прилагательного и причастия (их трудно различить, и поэтому различать не нужно). Полы лакированы:  то ли это качество (лаковое покрытие), то ли их лакировали.  И наречие слегка здесь не помощник.

Comment: " есть примеры причастий с одной Н и без зависимых слов": конечно, любое краткое причастие пишется с одной Н, не важно, есть ли там зависимые слова или нет. "Удивленная девочка" – причастие (т. к. от глагола сов. вида и заменяется на: девочка, которую удивили)"девочка удивлена". Вопрос-то не в этом, а в том, что вы назвали как "переводящие слова". "В общем случае зависимые слова ("переводящие") - это все слова, кроме наречий меры и степени" --- вот!!! про это я и пытаюсь выяснить! За эти слова глубокий Вам поклон, и я бы очень хотел увидеть их где-нибудь в том же Розентале, например :)

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую чуть позже дать отдельный ответ по зависимым словам, а то комментарии пропадут.  Кстати, я исправила ответ для прилагательного  "лакированный".